# use pagination with query strings in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i have pagination managed in codeigniter with following code:

```
 //start pagination
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'news/';

        $config['total_rows'] = $this->m_core->get_records_num();

       $config['per_page'] = $this->per_page;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $config['next_link'] = '&rsaquo;';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&lsaquo;';
        $config['last_link'] = '&raquo;';
        $config['first_link'] = '&laquo;';
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['wdx_pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        //end pagination
```

If i don't enable query string to TRUE, pagination is working fine. An example of an URL is the following:

`http://www.xxxxxx.ro/news/5` and the page is displayed.

If I enable query strings to TRUE, then the link above becomes like this:

`http://www.xxxxxxx.ro/news/&per_page=5` and it's not displaying the page.

My question is: what should I change so my pagination should work? I have to use query strings in my codeigniter application so i can't disable them. Is there a way to use pagination with query strings?

Answer (score 0):

if you use query string in URL then shouldn't use `uri_segment` in configuration. Try following

```
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->m_core->get_records_num();
    $config['per_page'] = $this->per_page;
    $config['num_links'] = 10;
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('news/index?a=' . $any_param);
    $config['next_link'] = '&rsaquo;';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lsaquo;';
    $config['last_link'] = '&raquo;';
    $config['first_link'] = '&laquo;';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: when i press the number of the pages..it always shows the same page..the pagination doesn't work!